# how to get selected item in <li> to views in django

Tags: html, django, django-views

please help !!!

I have a code which get the data from db and display it in dropdown menu, the problem is : i can't get the selected item to insert it in an other table

the html :

```
<form method="post"  >
        {% csrf_token %}
<div class="template-demo" >
                        <div class="mdc-select demo-width-class" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCSelect" >
                          

                          <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
                          <div class="mdc-select__selected-text"></div>
                          <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu-surface demo-width-class" >
                            
                            
                            <ul class="mdc-list">
                              <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" data-value="" aria-selected="true">
                              </li>
                              {% for TypeFrais in typefrais %}
                              <li class="mdc-list-item" >
                                <input type="hidden"  name="type_field">
                                {{TypeFrais.FRT_NAME}}
                              </li>
                              {% endfor%}
                              
                            </ul>

                          
                          </div>
                          <span class="mdc-floating-label">Type de frais</span>
                          <div class="mdc-line-ripple"> 
  
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
 <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" type="submit">
                        Ajouter
                      </button>
 </form>
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #iden = request.POST['id_field']
    designation = request.POST['des_field']
    date = request.POST['date_field']
    montant = request.POST['montant_field']
    type = request.POST['typefield']
    GES_FRAIS = Frais(FR_TYPE_id=type,FR_DESIGNATION=designation,FR_MONTANT=montant,FR_DATE=date,FR_CODE=78)
    GES_FRAIS.save()
    return render(request, 'gesfrais.html',context)
```

the error is :

***MultiValueDictKeyError at /dashboard/gesfrais/
'typefield'***

edit :

models :

```
class TypeFrais (models.Model):
FRT_ID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
FRT_NAME= models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
def __str__(self):
    return self.FRT_NAME

class Frais(models.Model):
FR_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
FR_TYPE = models.ForeignKey(TypeFrais, on_delete=CASCADE)
FR_DESIGNATION = models.TextField(max_length=255)
FR_MONTANT = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
FR_DATE = models.DateField()
FR_CODE = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.FR_DESIGNATION
```

Comment: Share your `models.py` file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.